# Why is China not driving the Indian troops in Doklam plateau out?

Tags: china

The Chinese government claims some Indian troops have been "illegally stationed in its territory" for over a month and, that it would not rule out the military action if diplomatic efforts to remove the troops failed.

This dispute of land ownership has made a stir in China, where many netizens have been angered by the delay in taking effective action. While the Chinese government is still holding talks with BRICS, with India included, for economic cooperation.

Why has the Chinese government delayed military action?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we generally don't answer questions which ask for personal opinions. Please only ask questions which can be answered objectively. For more information about what kind of questions are appropriate here, check out the "Asking" section of the [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: I think the question would be be legit once the OP rephrase "What is your opinion on it?" into "How can we explain that China is not taking military action in Doklam plateau ?"

Comment: I've rewritten this.  There are still problems with this question, as it need citations of the assertions it makes (have the Chinese given an ultimatum?, is there anger about the lack of action in China?) It seems to be making a point.

Comment: @Philipp you know it is not easy to make a distinction when the question is about politics, and the objectivity you mentioned does not exist in real life when it comes to political question. Please review your judgement.

Comment: @JamesK Thanks for your edit. But now it falls into [speculative](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3098/3135) territory. That doesn't make it much better.

Comment: @NanningYouth: Objectivity is hard to find in real-life politics, but it is still required on SE Politics, at least as long as facts are concerned and can be documented. Philipp was right in his comment: aking for "opinions" is pointless, and your questions fits better now tahnks to James K 's edit.

Comment: I mean, for example, when Russia is expelling the diplomats of America, will the US still hold talks with Russia for economic cooperation. The normal reaction is put on hold for the time being, but not having such matters going on. that is what makes me puzzled. If China thought it is not good for it, it should fight back, but why go on talking with its rival?

Comment: Russia is expelling 755 US diplomats, but doesn't ask for the embassy to get closed - 455 US diplomats are allowed to stay, and the same number of Russian diplomats are in their US embassy. The main function of those officials is for both countries to talk to each other ! Diplomacy is basically the relationships between countries, even (and especially) if they are rivals to some extends. And trying to keep this rivalry in peace-time boundaries.

Comment: It is because even the CCP knows that it is a disputed territory and it is not 15th century where they can unilaterally send their troops to occupy other countries' territories.

Answer (score 4):

Nationalist feelings aside, the territory in question, Doklam plateau, is contested. China claims it's Chinese, Bhutan claims it's Bhutanese, and India backs Bhutan. I won't take a stand on the matter, but internet is full of literature about the history of this dispute ([source 1](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/jul/06/china-india-bhutan-standoff-disputed-territory), [source 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doklam))

While the plateau holds strategic importance for each of these three countries, it is not worth for any of them to get involved in a big military confrontation. So what we are witnessing with troops deployed both by India and China is merely each side testing the other's resolve and trying to get strategic or diplomatic concessions from the opponent - *without* starting a large-scale fight.

That may also be described as playing with fire, but neither side actually wants an incident to ignite the conflict. Of course, we still have no warranty such an incident won't happen, especially when public opinions on both sides are inflamed with nationalist propaganda.

Comment: Sorry for the wording. But my intention is to know why China can still hold talks with an enemy for other matters (economic cooperation) when this very enemy is being hostile to it? Territory problem is a very complicated matter, which I don't think even the coming generations can solve it well to the satisfaction of all parties concerned.

Comment: That's almost a different question. In spite of this dispute and others, there's no state of war (thanksfully!) between China and India at the moment, so India is not considered an "enemy" by China's government. It may be an annoying neighbour or a geopolitical opponent, but that doesn't prevent diplomatic talks nor economic cooperation. Note that China, on the other hand, has no diplomatic echanges with Bhutan.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in China's reception of the BRICS minister meetings which took place during the border dispute, President Xi of China said to the Indian representative that he would like to send his best regards to Indian leaders, so do you think it is normal for a country to do so?

Comment: "sending best regards" can be the expression of warm feelings as well as neutral, poilte, empty, formulation. I've no idea what was President Xi precise meaning it that specific case, but I'd not be surprised if it happened to be just standard diplomatic phrasing.

Comment: @NanningYouth: Because it is China that is creating the hostility, by trying to occupy Bhutanese territory.  Presumably they think this will be to their long-term advantage, just as they think it to their advantage to hold talks on other matters.

Comment: @NanningYouth "*why China can still hold talks with an enemy ... when this very enemy is being hostile to it?*" Unless India is actually shooting at Chinese forces (occasional "pot shots" don't count), then **no** India **is not being hostile** no matter what Chinese political organs say.

Comment: @NanningYouth things like this happen **all the time**.  Go back and look at the Cold War, and how West and Soviet forces frequently buzzed each other.  Quite a few planes were shot down, ships and submarines crashed into each other, etc.  There was a **lot** of mistrust.  But still we kept talking and never went to war.